# Need to display day of week from timestamp in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking to pull the day of week from a `created` column (data type is timestamp), in a table and total the results by day for the entire dataset. Example

`surveys` table

```
2016-03-21 20:21:30
2016-03-21 20:23:23
2016-03-21 20:24:07
2016-03-22 14:21:20
2016-03-25 12:05:41
2016-03-29 11:33:02
2016-03-29 23:44:03
2016-04-04 15:10:27
```

Expected output would be:

```
Monday - 4
Tuesday - 3
Friday - 1
```

Comment: Step 1: extract day. Step 2: GROUP BY.

Comment: Step 3: count()

Comment: Use the `DAYNAME()` function to get the day of week.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just tested this on sqlfiddle. you can ignore these create and insert commands as you already have the data.

```
create table yourTable (created timestamp);
insert into yourTable values ('2016-03-21 20:21:30');
insert into yourTable values ('2016-03-21 20:23:23');
insert into yourTable values ('2016-03-21 20:24:07');
insert into yourTable values ('2016-03-22 14:21:20');
insert into yourTable values ('2016-03-25 12:05:41');
insert into yourTable values ('2016-03-29 11:33:02');
insert into yourTable values ('2016-03-29 23:44:03');
insert into yourTable values ('2016-04-04 15:10:27');

SELECT   count(created), --get the count of days
         dayname(created) AS day --function to get the day of the week via the date
FROM     yourTable
GROUP BY day --seperates the data according the the day of the week
```

this returns your expected result set.

```
count(created)    day
  1               Friday  
  4               Monday  
  3               Tuesday
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to count values of date fields https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html

and then show it with DAYNAME() function https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Eg. "TABLE" is a table name and DATE_HOUR is a name of field with date

```
SELECT DAYNAME(DATE_HOUR), count(DATE_HOUR)
FROM `TABLE`
GROUP BY DATE_HOUR
```